# SIM for travel in both Germany (Berlin + Dresden) and Czech Republic (Prague)

Tags: cellphones

Title more or less says it all.

We are flying into Berlin, taking the train to Dresden then train to Prague.
We'd like to be able to make calls (local) and have data access (email, maps, browsing, etc) while there.  Both phones are unlocked iPhones, we use AT&T.

Will be traveling for two weeks, 2/3 of the time in Germany, 1/3 in Czech Republic.

Is there a SIM that we can get that covers both countries well or do we need to purchase one in each country OR is [AT&T's International Day Pass](https://www.att.com/international/day-pass/) the better option?  Ideally both our phones would have access while we're away (I Know that means two SIMs).  Seems like AT&T would run $15.00 a day for the two of us so $200+ for the trip (which seems exuberant.)

So, Is there one carrier we can purchase when we land (or in advance) that would cover us in both countries?

Comment: This question has been closed as a duplicate because SIM card pricing (including any roaming charges) changes *very* frequently and we prefer giving out generic advice on how to find the best offer rather than links to specific offers. This particular question is about a multi-country SIM card but the point remains the same nonetheless.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The European Union has removed roaming restrictions a few years ago so if you buy a German SIM card you are good to go.

For example, LIDL Connect says

> LIDL Connect SMART XL: When you activate it for the first time, you have a starting credit of €10. You can use the following inclusive services for €17.99/4 weeks: Free calls and SMS to all German networks (telephony for national standard calls and/or national standard SMS, each to all German networks, not to special numbers and abroad 60/60 rate) and a mobile Internet flat rate with 12 GB with a max./advertised bandwidth of 25 Mbit/s in download and 10 Mbit/s in upload, from consumption of the data volume 64 kbit/s in upload/download . **Applies in Germany and other EU countries**.

Not at all accidentally, LIDL Connect is one I would suggest mostly because it's cheap as dirt and LIDL is everywhere. You will need id and proof of address, your hotel will do.

Comment: Do they offer solid coverage in your experiences?  Would be able to find at the airport or hotel?

Comment: It's using Vodafone. In cities it doesn't matter really. If you want Telekom instead then try https://www.congstar.de/ . Buying SIM cards at airports are typically not best, those are typically tourist traps. There are more than 3000 LIDL supermarkets in Germany, finding one shouldn't be hard.

Comment: Is LIDL SIM available for purchase in prague?

Comment: No but OP said they are flying into Berlin first, I answered that question. I am not familiar with Czech SIM offers -- but the gist of the answer, the "buy a SIM, it's good EU wide" is the same.

Comment: Note that Lidl is primarily a discounter/ supermarket, not a mobile phone company. That means you can buy these sim cards in any Lidl supermarket. They exist in both Germany and in the Czech republic. Technically, Lidl is just a third party reseller, the actual mobile phone service comes from Vodafone, but this shouldn't be relevant for your user experience.

Comment: Lidl is in both countries, but in the Czech Republic they do not sell their SIM cards.

Comment: Take a note that you have to register the SIM card, and it doesn't work immediately. The registration takes some time (day or two). Also, I don't think that roaming works for lidl connect.  At least I can't call when I am outside of Germany. No idea if something needs to be enabled.

Comment: @BЈовић When you say roaming does not seem to work outside of Germany, what about data?

Comment: @chx Have you experienced "The registration takes some time (day or two)"?  On previous trips (Italy, UK) when a SIM was purchased, registration was complete as soon as we were able to get a WiFi connection to use to setup an account.

Comment: @JasonReljac I do have lidl connect, and neither data nor calls worked outside of germany. But as I said, maybe I have to set something up. Maybe I disabled it on my phone

Comment: @JasonReljac I can't speak to LIDL Connect in particular, but having used a prepaid SIM I purchased over the counter in Poland, it functioned flawlessly in three different countries (CZ, DE, NL) before eventually being shut off because I'd exhausted the balance. You _do_ need to enable roaming on your phone, though - by default, it'll be turned off, especially for handsets used primarily outside the EU.

Comment: One thing to note is that the eu-fair-use policy limits the volume outside of your "home" country: Since january 1st you can only use TotalPrice/2,975€ GB outside of the country:
E.g. if you have 15GB for 12 euro (thats what I have) I can only use ~5GB outside of germany 
https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/consumers/internet-telecoms/mobile-roaming-costs/index_en.htm

Edit: This is only correct for unlimited data, for limited data other restrictions might apply tho so you might want to check that out

Comment: I don't know about LIDL connect in particular but I once ran into problems activating a similar SIM card from a different supermarket because I did not have a credit card registered with a German address! Can you confirm that the Hotel Address will work and you don't need to activate using a 'German' credit card? If that works then it's definitely something to keep in mind before picking another supermarket SIM from a competitor which may not activate as easily.

Answer (score 1):

In the past I have used third party sim cards in Europe. They are cheap and work well, but you will get a new phone number and that can cause problems. For instance, if you want to buy something on Amazon, it will send a code to your phone. You have to switch sim cards to get that code and then go back and enter it. That is just a pain to switch back and forth. I now have T-Mobile in the States and their free international roaming does fine for me. It is 2G speed, but it is free. If you want more then you can pay $10/day or $35 or $50 for longer periods. The AT&T International Day Pass is probably similar to the paid option for T-Mobile. The free European roaming is one of the major reasons I switched to T-Mobile as I go to Europe two or three times a year.